# Add duplicate items(string) in doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am currently figuring out the implementation of double linked list. As strange as it may sound, I ***want*** repetitive items added to my linked list.
I am adding newNode to the list in sorted order.

The below function does not add the repetitive nodes.

```
struct Node
{
    char name[42];
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};

void addSorted(struct Node **head, struct Node *newNode)
{
    struct Node* current;
    // Special case for the head end
    if ((*head == NULL) || strcmp((*head)->name, newNode->name) >= 0)
    {
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // Locate the Node before the point of insertion
        current = *head;
        while (current->next != NULL &&
                strcmp(current->next->name, newNode->name) <= 0)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        newNode->next = current->next;
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}

struct Node* GetNewNode(char *name)
{
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));

    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Some Irrelevant Code
    if (strncmp(operator, "a", 1) == 0)
    {
        temp = GetNewNode(name);

        addSorted(&head, temp);
    }
 }
```

Comment: "The below function does not add the repetitive function". Please clarify. Do you mean you haven't attempted to implement that or you have but it doesn't work? If the latter please describe what it is doing instead.

Comment: I have tried changing comparison switch, but I am unable to implement the required solution.

Comment: Again, please tell us the current behaviour of your program. It crashes? It doesn't add repeated nodes at all? It adds but sometimes in the wrong place? Always in the wrong place? etc...

Comment: It DOES NOT add repetitive nodes at all.

Comment: please attach your codes of calling addSorted.

Comment: Does repetitive nodes mean duplicate items?  i.e. items with the same name?

Comment: It is a potential problem that you always ignore to compare the first head item.

Comment: @Will I have added the calling codes and additional newNode creation function.

Comment: Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem. It's really not clear how to reproduce it. Your code works ok in [this simple example](http://ideone.com/yKRSLq).

Comment: if your `operator` is `'a'`, I think it always links the `temp` node into your linked list, no matter what the `name` is.

Comment: First you need to decide what type of list you are building? A **circular-list** or a **linear head/tail** list. In `addSorted` when you set `newNode->next = *head;` instead of `newNode->next = NULL;` you are creating a **circular** list. (that will take more corrections to your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main point is that you have not taken care of the **prev** pointer and also for the first if, there should be two cases,

```
if(*head==NULL)
{
 *head=newNode;
}
else if(strcmp((*head)->name, newNode->name) >= 0)
{
 (*head)->prev=newNode;//ADD THIS LINE
 newNode->next = *head;
 *head = newNode;
}
```

In the else condition make the following changes

```
newNode->next = current->next;
current->next->prev = newNode;//CHANGE HERE
current->next=newNode;//ADD THIS LINE
newNode->prev=current;//ADD THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to manager the `prev` pointer as already discussed, there are some additional areas where you are asking for trouble. First it is wise to use a `define` to set the size of your static `name` array (this will become a necessity to validate the size of `name`):

```
#define MAXN

struct Node
{
    char name[MAXN];    /* use a define for static allocation size */
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};
```

This feeds into two issues in `GetNewNode`. First you need to validate your memory allocation:

```
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));

    if (!newNode) { /* validate all memory allocations */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() memory allocation failed.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

You then must also validate the length of `name` to prevent writing beyond the end of your array if `name > 41 chars`:

```
    size_t namelen = strlen (name);

    if ( namelen > MAXN - 1) { /* validate string length */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() name length (%zu) exceeds %d .\n", 
                 __func__, namelen, MAXN);
        return NULL;
    }
```

**Note:** by using a `define` to set the length of `name`, the define `MAXL` is available to you as your length validation test.

Next, in `GetNewNode` you validate the length of `name` and returned `NULL` -- you must now handle the return in `main()` along with providing a declaration for `head`:

```
int main (void)
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;               /* head must be declared */

    if (strncmp(operator, "a", 1) == 0)
    {
        temp = GetNewNode(name);

        if (temp)                           /* validate return  */
            addSorted(&head, temp);
    }
}
```

If your intent was to create a **circular-list** then you have several additional conditions you must test for and respond appropriately to in `addSorted`. Specifically, you must (1) create the list when `*head = NULL`.

If your earlier statement `newNode->next = *head; *head = newNode;` was correct, you must then (2) account for the condition when the list is **self-referencial** (i.e. only one-node present that refers to itself).

You then have two more conditions to test (3) whether `newNode->name` sorts before the current `(*head)->name` where you must insert `newNode` as the **new first node** in the list; and finally (4) the case where `newNode->name` sorts after the current `(*head)->name`.

Even with a **linear head/tail** list with you will need to address both **(3) & (4)** above. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -2):

With a doubly linked list, it is best to first find the spot where you need to insert it.

```
// pseudo code
current = head;
while (current) 
{
    if ( strcmp( name, current -> name) ... )  // your logic for your sort order
    {

    }
    current = current->next;
}
```

Once you find the spot to insert, you have one four cases to deal with when you want to insert an item into the into the list.   You have to handle head/tail changing as well as pointing inward and outward or to null as needed.

- Add to a completely empty list  (head and tail point to the record, prev and next are null)
- Add to the front (head gets a new value, new record prev is null,)
- Add to end ( tail gets a new value, new record next is null)
- Add to middle ( head/tail unchanged )

Comment: Why the down vote?  The user states that it is a doubly linked list and has not addressed the tail pointer at all.